# Laravel where on relationship object

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship, where-clause

I'm developing a web API with Laravel 5.0 but I'm not sure about a specific query I'm trying to build.

My classes are as follows:

```
class Event extends Model {

    protected $table = 'events';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function participants()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Participant', 'IDEvent', 'ID');
    }

    public function owner()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\User', 'ID', 'IDOwner');
    }
}
```

and

```
class Participant extends Model {

    protected $table = 'participants';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongTo('App\User', 'IDUser', 'ID');
    }

    public function event()
    {
        return $this->belongTo('App\Event', 'IDEvent', 'ID');
    }
}
```

Now, I want to get all the events with a specific participant.
I tried with:

```
Event::with('participants')->where('IDUser', 1)->get();
```

but the `where` condition is applied on the `Event` and not on its `Participants`. The following gives me an exception:

```
Participant::where('IDUser', 1)->event()->get();
```

I know that I can write this:

```
$list = Participant::where('IDUser', 1)->get();
for($item in $list) {
   $event = $item->event;
   // ... other code ...
}
```

but it doesn't seem very efficient to send so many queries to the server.

What is the best way to perform a `where` through a model relationship using Laravel 5 and Eloquent?

Comment: What was the exception?

Answer (score 335, accepted):

The correct syntax to do this on your relations is:

```
Event::whereHas('participants', function ($query) {
    return $query->where('IDUser', '=', 1);
})->get();
```

This will return Events where Participants have a user ID of 1. If the Participant doesn't have a user ID of 1, the Event will NOT be returned.

Read more at https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: To help readers understand: This will return Events where Participants have a user ID of 1. If the Participant doesn't have a user ID of 1, the Event will NOT be returned.

Comment: I'm really sorry. I just confused and send the comment in the wrong thread

Comment: @ChuckLeButt your comment should be editted in this answer. Your comment has good value.

Comment: is their a orWhereHas?

Answer (score 128):

@Cermbo's answer is not related to this question. In that answer, `Laravel` will give you all `Events` if each `Event` has `'participants'` with `IdUser` of `1`.

But if you want to get all `Events` with all `'participants'` provided that all `'participants'` have a `IdUser` of 1, then you should do something like this :

```
Event::with(["participants" => function($q){
    $q->where('participants.IdUser', '=', 1);
}])
```

N.B:

In `where` use your table name, not Model name.

Comment: To help readers understand: Unlike the other answer, this will return ALL Events, whether the Participant has a user ID of 1 or not, but will only include the Participant object if they do.

Answer (score 61):

**for laravel 8.57+**

```
Event::whereRelation('participants', 'IDUser', '=', 1)->get();
```

Comment: Here's the original [pull request](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/38499), if anyone needs to understand how it works.

Comment: Horny. Super thing. Also works like so:
```php
Event::whereRelation('participants', 'IDUser', 1)->get();
```

Answer (score 19):

With multiple joins, use something like this code:

```
$userId = 44;
Event::with(["owner", "participants" => function($q) use($userId ){
    $q->where('participants.IdUser', '=', 1);
    //$q->where('some other field', $userId );
}])
```

Comment: What sould be $someId value?

Comment: @FernandoTorres `$someId`   is another variable which you can't user directly inside this function so you need to pass in `use(...` method.

Answer (score 11):

Use this code:

```
return Deal::with(["redeem" => function($q){
    $q->where('user_id', '=', 1);
}])->get();
```

Comment: This will not filter out `Deal` based on the relation condition. Instead it will only load the relation if the condition is met.

Answer (score 7):

for laravel 8 use this instead

```
Event::whereHas('participants', function ($query) {
     $query->where('user_id', '=', 1);
})->get();
```

this will return events that only with partcipats with user id 1 with that event relastionship,

Comment: This works perfectly on laravel V-10

Answer (score 3):

I created a custom query scope in BaseModel (my all models extends this class):

```
/**
 * Add a relationship exists condition (BelongsTo).
 *
 * @param  Builder        $query
 * @param  string|Model   $relation   Relation string name or you can try pass directly model and method will try guess relationship
 * @param  mixed          $modelOrKey
 * @return Builder|static
 */
public function scopeWhereHasRelated(Builder $query, $relation, $modelOrKey = null)
{
    if ($relation instanceof Model && $modelOrKey === null) {
        $modelOrKey = $relation;
        $relation   = Str::camel(class_basename($relation));
    }

    return $query->whereHas($relation, static function (Builder $query) use ($modelOrKey) {
        return $query->whereKey($modelOrKey instanceof Model ? $modelOrKey->getKey() : $modelOrKey);
    });
}
```

You can use it in many contexts for example:

```
Event::whereHasRelated('participants', 1)->isNotEmpty(); // where has participant with id = 1
```

Furthermore, you can try to omit relationship name and pass just model:

```
$participant = Participant::find(1);
Event::whereHasRelated($participant)->first(); // guess relationship based on class name and get id from model instance
```

Answer (score 0):

[OOT]

A bit OOT, but this question is the most closest topic with my question.

Here is an example if you want to show Event where **ALL** participant meet certain requirement. Let's say, event where ALL the participant has *fully paid*. So, it WILL NOT return events which having one or more participants that haven't fully paid .

Simply use the `whereDoesntHave` of the others 2 statuses.

Let's say the statuses are haven't paid at all [eq:1], paid some of it [eq:2], and fully paid [eq:3]

```
Event::whereDoesntHave('participants', function ($query) {
   return $query->whereRaw('payment = 1 or payment = 2');
})->get();
```

Tested on Laravel 5.8 - 7.x

Comment: The things i like about this is, u still can get the relation object such as `Event::with(['participants, avenue])`