# How Laravel generates SQL queries

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I have created a one-to-many relationship. Here are the model classes.

```
class Photo extends Model
{
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}

class User extends Authenticatable
{ 
    public function photos(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Photo');
    }
}
```

Then I try to retrieve photos:

```
$photos = User::find(1)->photos->where('photo', 'ut.jpg')->first();
```

Here is a query log I got. I do not see the photo='ut.jpg'. So how laravel generate SQL?

```
select * from `photos` where `photos`.`user_id` = 1 and `photos`.`user_id` is not null
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel where on relationship object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29989908/laravel-where-on-relationship-object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$photos = User::find(1)->photos()->where('photo', 'ut.jpg')->first();
```

must be use `->photos()` instead of `->photos`.

For see sql query use

```
$sql = User::find(1)->photos()->where('photo', 'ut.jpg')->toSql();
```

Answer (score 1):

You queried all photos by using this:

```
$photos = User::find(1)->photos->where('photo', 'ut.jpg')->first();
```

By using `User::find(1)->photos` you receive a [Laravel Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections). Those collections have a `where` method as well. So basically, you are running SQL to get all photos of `User 1` and then you just filter that collection to only show you the item with photo `ut.jpg`.

Instead, you can use brackets to get the relationship, and then query that.
Your query then becomes

```
$photos = User::find(1)->photos()->where('photo', 'ut.jpg')->first();
```

Instead of naming it `$photos` you should name it `$photo`, as you are querying with `first` - which will result only in one object (or null).

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this:

```
$photo = 'ut.jpg';

$photos = User::find(1)->whereHas('photos', function ($query) use($photo){
return $query->where('photo', $photo);
})->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

your query `$photos = User::find(1)->photos->where('photo', 'ut.jpg')->first();` is incorrect, laravel didnt see the where condition if you do this

```
User::whereHas('photos', function($q) {
      $q->where('photo', 'ut.jpg');

})->where('id',1)->first();
```

thats the correct query to get the user photo

Comment: I took the example from the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many. $comment = App\Post::find(1)->comments()->where('title', 'foo')->first(); The result that i got is correct. But the query not.

Comment: @user3351236 $comment = App\Post::find(1)->comments()->where('title', 'foo')->first(); the where condition is on the post not the comment and the one you did was on the photo not the user

Answer (score 0):

You could:
Run A Select Query

```
$photos = DB::select('select * from photos where id = ?', [1]);
```

All this is well-documented in :
--https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/database