# query not stacking in laravel

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a query that i am trying to insert a value based on a forum post results. Boiling it down  to this

```
$users->whereIn('id', $viewedIds);
$rdata = $users->with('profile')->where('gender', '=', $searchGender)->orderBy('last_login')->simplePaginate(8);
```

Which doesn't work. but this does.

```
$rdata = $users->with('profile')->where('gender', '=', $searchGender)->whereIn('id', $viewedIds)->orderBy('last_login')->simplePaginate(8);
```

but I cant do that with form post data.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel where on relationship object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29989908/laravel-where-on-relationship-object)

Comment: `with` can be used during queries before get/first/all, but `load` can work on initiated query, like your stack of queries.

Comment: Ron - it helps but they way they are using the eloquent model is different and they are not adding on to a existing query.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to start my query with  $users = User::query() instead of $users = new User();